# How to change the defualt behavior of drag event in Highcharts or Highstock？

Tags: highcharts

when I drag in the chart, it triggered a zoom action, how to change it to the behavior like Google Map? drag the map, map will move, and scale the map with mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

1. download Highmaps
2. import highmaps/modules/map.js into html file
3. add mapNavigation option to the chart:

   mapNavigation: {
       enabled: true,
       enableButtons: false
   }